# undefined method `total_pages' for #<Advertisement::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe4cdd7df98>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I am trying to search through tags, and it was working fine. But after i started to use `gem will_paginate` for pagination, i can't do that because i am getting this error:

```
undefined method 'total_pages' for #<Advertisement::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe4cdd7df98>
```

But if I search for an unknown tag it works fine (show an empty list of ads on index page).

`advertisemts_controller.rb`

```
class AdvertisementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_advertisement, only: %i[edit update destroy]

  def index
    @advertisements = Advertisement.paginate(page: params[:page], 
    per_page: 2)
  end

  def show
    @advertisement = Advertisement.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @advertisement = Advertisement.new
  end

  def create
    @advertisement = Advertisements::Create.call(advertisement_params)

    if @advertisement.errors.blank?
      redirect_to advertisement_path(@advertisement),
                notice: 'The advertisement was successfully added.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @advertisement.update(advertisement_params)
      redirect_to @advertisement, notice: 'Advertisement was 
                                           successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @advertisement.destroy
    redirect_to advertisements_path, notice: 'Advertisement was 
  successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private

  def set_advertisement
    @advertisement = current_user.advertisements.find(params[:id])
  end

  def advertisement_params
    params
      .require(:advertisement)
      .permit(:title, :description, :user_id, :tags)
      .merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

`search_queries_controller.rb`

```
class SearchQueriesController < ApplicationController
  def search_by_tag
    @advertisements = Advertisement.find_by_tags(tags_params)

    render 'advertisements/index'
  end

  private

  def tags_params
    params.fetch(:tags, '')
  end
end
```

`advertisement.rb`

```
class Advertisement < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :advertisement_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :comments
  has_many   :tags, through: :advertisement_tags
  belongs_to :user

  validates :title,
            :description,
            presence: true

  def self.find_by_tags(tags)
    Advertisement.joins(:tags).where('tags.tag_name IN (?)', 
                                      tags.split(/[\s,']/))
  end
end
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, I am using `ruby-2.3.4` and `rails-5.1.2`, `will_paginate-3.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because

```
def search_by_tag
  @advertisements = Advertisement.find_by_tags(tags_params)

  render 'advertisements/index'
end
```

doesn't call `paginate` method on the relation, but renders the view which uses pagination.

You may even notice that `Advertisement.all.paginate(page: 1).total_pages` works, but `Advertisement.all.total_pages` doesn't.

Something like

```
def search_by_tag
  @advertisements = Advertisement
    .find_by_tags(tags_params)
    .paginate(page: 1, per_page: 2)

  render 'advertisements/index'
end
```

should fix the problem